# Characterizing density functions

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $f$ and $g$ be two density functions. If I have :
$${\ln\left(\int_0^{\infty}e^{-sx}f(x)\ dx\right)\over \int_0^{\infty}xf(x)\ dx}={\ln\left(\int_0^{\infty}e^{-sx}g(x)\ dx\right)\over \int_0^{\infty}xg(x)\ dx},\ \forall s\in (a,b)\subset \mathbb{R}$$

For which classes of functions the equality is satisfied?

If I let $f$ and $g$ be two Gamma densities with the same rate parameter then this equality holds with $a=-\infty$ and $b=\mathrm{Rate\ Parameter}$.

Is this characterization even possible for a given $(a,b)$?

A sub question would be given $s\in (-\infty,b)$ then does $f$ and $g$ has to be Gamma densities with the same rate parameter $\beta=b $?.

Comment: Are you sure you want "$\forall s \in \mathbb{C}$"? I feel like you'll run into issues when taking the logarithm of a complex number. Also, even if restricted to $s \in \mathbb{R}$ and considering the case of Gamma densities, the numerators are undefined when $-s$ is larger than the rate parameter.

Comment: You are right. For the Gamma densities it only makes sense if $s<\beta$. So if we restrict the domain of $s\in (0,b)$ for some $b$. is it possible to determine the densities?

Comment: Presumably you  want to assume $f$ and $g$ are supported on the non-negative reals.

Comment: Correct,  $x>0$. I guess a characterization is hard given a domain $s\in (a,b)$. so for now I am trying to find another example beside the Gamma densities.

Comment: Let me guess an answer: any infinitely divisible non-negative rv.  Some have densities and some do not.  Compound Poisson rvs are a rich source of examples, probably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a class of examples, as sketched in a comment, based on [compound Poisson distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_Poisson_distribution), which are examples of [infinitely divisible distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_divisibility_(probability)).  Let $h$ be a density function, supported on the positive reals, for which $\int_0^\infty xh(x)dx<\infty$.
Let $$f=\sum_{k\ge0} e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^k}{k!} h^{*k}$$  where $h^{*k}$ denotes the $k$-th convolution power of $h$, and where $\lambda>0$ is a real number.  Then $f$ is the density of a random variable $S=X_1+X_2+\cdots +X_N$ where the $X_i$ are iid with density $h$ and $N$ is a Poisson random variable with expectation $\lambda$. That is, $S$ is the sum of a random number of independent summands; it has what is called a *compound Poisson distribution*. If $EX_i<\infty$ it can be checked that $ES = \int_0^\infty x f(x)dx=\lambda EX_i$. Similarly construct $g=\sum \exp(-\mu) \mu^k h^{*k}/k!$, the density function for $T=X_1+X_2+\cdots+ X_M$ where $M$ is Poisson with parameter $\mu>0$. Now $ES=\mu EX_1$.  If $\eta(s)=E\exp(-sX_i)$ one can check that $$E\exp(-s S) = \int_0^\infty e^{-sx}f(x)dx = \sum_{k\ge0}\exp(-\lambda)\lambda^k \eta(s)^k/k!=\exp(\lambda(\eta(s)-1))$$
and $$E\exp(-sT) = \exp(\mu(\eta(s)-1)).$$ There is some non empty interval $I\subseteq\mathbb R$  for which these integrals and sums converge for all $s\in\mathbb C$ for which $\Re s\in I$.

It is easy to evaluate the ratios in the problem statement:$$\frac{\log\int_0^\infty \exp(-sx)f(x)dx}{\int_0^\infty x(f(x)dx} = \frac{\lambda(\eta(s)-1)}{ES} = \frac{\lambda(\eta(s)-1)}{\lambda EX_1}=\frac {\eta(s)-1}{EX_1},$$
and similarly for the ratio involving $g$, which works out to the same thing.  If the initial density function $h$ is, say, the uniform density on $[0,1]$, these examples are different from OP's examples.

Afterthought.  Non infinitely divisible examples exist, too.  Let $f=u*u$ and $g=u*u*u$ where $u=\chi_{[0,1]}$ is the probability density function  of a $U[0,1]$ random variable; $f$ is the density function for $X=U_1+U_2$ and $g$ the density for $Y=U_1+U_2+U_3$ where the $U_i\sim U[0,1]$ are iid.  Then $E\exp(-sX)=\phi(s)^2$ and $E\exp(-sY)$, where $\phi(s)=\int_0^1\exp(-su)du$; obviously $EX=2/2$ and $EY=3/2$, and obviously $$\frac{\log \phi(s)^2}{2/2} = \frac{\log \phi(s)^3}{3/2}.$$
But the distribution $U[0,1]$ is not infinitely divisible, and neither is that of $X$ or $Y$.  In such examples, the ratio $r = EX/EY$ is a rational number. I do not know of non-infinitely divisible examples where $r$ is irrational.

Comment: Thank you kimchi, this is a nice distribution class.

Comment: @Inquisor It's not clear to me if all examples of your phenomenon arise this way.  Infinitely divisible leads to one cumulant generating function being a scalar multiple of the other, but conversely?  If I think of anything, I'll edit my post.